# Unit testing vue components with Jest issue

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-component

I'm struggling trying to unit test some components in an app and I would really apreciate if someone could help me.
I've already set up the Jest enviroment for testing in Vue and things work just fine until I try to test a component that rely on other modules with functions in it. These functions are helpers useful for importing vuex actions and getters quicker in the components. Here there are some lines of code that I hope could help with the problem:

- this is the error that Jest throws in the console:

```
/app # yarn test:unit /common / page - header / ProjectWizard.spec.js
yarn run v1 .22 .5
$ jest / common / page - header / ProjectWizard.spec.js
FAIL src / specs / common / page - header / projectWizard.spec.js
● Test suite failed to run

Configuration error:

  Could not locate module @ / state / helpers mapped as:
  /app/$1.

Please check your configuration
for these entries: {
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "/^@\/(.*)$/": "/app/$1"
  },
  "resolver": undefined
}

57 |
  import VueGoogleAutocomplete from '../../../node_modules/vue-google-autocomplete'
58 |
  > 59 |
  import {
    |
    ^
    60 | contractTypesMethods,
    61 | contractTypesGetters,
    62 | installationTypesMethods,

    at createNoMappedModuleFoundError(node_modules / jest - resolve / build / index.js: 551: 17)
    at src / components / builder / ProjectWizard.vue: 59: 1
    at Object. < anonymous > (src / components / builder / ProjectWizard.vue: 491: 3)
```

- this is the ProjectWizard file:

```
<template>
  <form-wizard
    @on-complete="onComplete(model)"
    error-color="#f1b44c"
    color="#EC641C"
    nextButtonText="Avanti"
    backButtonText="Indietro"
    :finishButtonText="(isModifying) ? 'Conferma modifiche' : 'Crea Progetto'"
    id="project-form-wizard"
    style="overflow: hidden;"
  >

    <tab-content title="Informazioni preliminari" icon="mdi mdi-folder-information" :before-change="validateFirstTab">

      <vue-form-generator-component :model="model" :schema="zeroTabSchema" :options="formOptions" ref="zeroTabSchema">
      </vue-form-generator-component>

      <b-form-group featured class="col-12" label="Indirizzo (Via etc.)" label-for="indirizzo-progetto">
        <vue-google-autocomplete required keypress types="" ref="address" id="indirizzo-progetto"
          classname="form-control" placeholder="Inserisci qui l'indirizzo del progetto"
          v-on:placechanged="getAddressData" country="it">
        </vue-google-autocomplete>
      </b-form-group>

      <vue-form-generator-component :model="model" :schema="firstTabSchema" :options="formOptions" ref="firstTabForm">
      </vue-form-generator-component>

    </tab-content>
    <tab-content 
      title="Dettagli progetto"
      icon="mdi mdi-home-search-outline" 
      :before-change="validateSecondTab"
    >

      <vue-form-generator-component
        :model="model" 
        :schema="secondTabSchema"
        :options="formOptions" 
        ref="secondTabForm"
      ></vue-form-generator-component>

    </tab-content>
  </form-wizard>
</template>

<script>
import {
  FormWizard,
  TabContent
} from "vue-form-wizard";

import VueFormGenerator from 'vue-form-generator'
import {
  resources
} from "../../../src/utils/validation"
Object.assign(VueFormGenerator.validators.resources, resources)
import VueGoogleAutocomplete from '../../../node_modules/vue-google-autocomplete'

import {
  contractTypesMethods,
  contractTypesGetters,
  installationTypesMethods,
  installationTypesGetters,
  interventionTypesMethods,
  interventionTypesGetters,
  contactsMethods,
  projectManagementMethods,
  projectManagementGetters,
  projectsMethods
} from "@/state/helpers";

// STATELESS
import {
  fetchContacts
} from '@/stateless/modules/common'

export default {
  data() {
    var vm = this;
    return {
      ...contractTypesGetters,
      ...installationTypesGetters,
      ...interventionTypesGetters,
      ...projectManagementGetters,
      
      contractTypes: [],
      selectedContract: "",
      installationTypesFiltered: [],
      interventionTypesFiltered: [],
      installationTypes: [],
      interventionTypes: [],
      contactPersons: [],
      address: '',
      model: {
        projectName: '',
        address: {
          partialStreet: '',
          streetNumber: '',
          city: '',
          province: '',
          country: '',
          CAP: '',
          state: ''
        },
        contractType: '',
        installationType: '',
        interventionType: '',
        contactPerson: '',
        description: ''
      },
      formOptions: {
        validationErrorClass: "has-error",
        validationSuccessClass: "has-success",
        validateAfterChanged: true,
      },
      zeroTabSchema: {
        fields: [{
            type: "input",
            inputType: "text",
            label: "Nome del progetto",
            model: "projectName",
            required: true,
            featured: true,
            maxlength: 64,
            validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string,
            styleClasses: 'col-12'
          },]
      },
      firstTabSchema: {
        fields: [
          {
            type: "input",
            inputType: "text",
            label: "Via",
            model: "address.partialStreet",
            required: true,
            featured: true,
            maxlength: 128,
            validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string,
            styleClasses: 'col-6'
          },
          {
            type: "input",
            inputType: "text",
            label: "Numero civico",
            model: "address.streetNumber",
            required: true,
            featured: true,
            maxlength: 16,
            validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string,
            styleClasses: 'col-6'
          },
          {
            type: "input",
            inputType: "text",
            label: "Città",
            model: "address.city",
            required: true,
            featured: true,
            maxlength: 64,
            validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string,
            styleClasses: 'col-6'
          },
          {
            type: "input",
            inputType: "text",
            label: "Provincia",
            model: "address.province",
            required: true,
            featured: true,
            maxlength: 2,
            validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string,
            styleClasses: 'col-6'
          },
          {
            type: "input",
            inputType: "text",
            label: "Paese",
            model: "address.country",
            required: true,
            featured: true,
            maxlength: 32,
            validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string,
            styleClasses: 'col-6'
          },
          {
            type: "input",
            inputType: "text",
            label: "CAP",
            model: "address.CAP",
            required: true,
            featured: true,
            min: 5,
            maxlength: 8,
            validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string,
            styleClasses: 'col-6'
          },
          {
            type: "input",
            inputType: "text",
            visible: false,
            label: "Regione",
            model: "address.state",
            required: true,
            featured: true,
            maxlength: 32,
            validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string,
            styleClasses: 'col-6'
          },
        ]
      },
      secondTabSchema: {
        fields: [{
            type: "select",
            label: "Tipo di appalto",
            model: "contractType",
            required: true,
            featured: true,
            validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string,
            styleClasses: 'col-12',
            selectOptions: {
              hideNoneSelectedText: true
            },
            onChanged(event) {
              const filterdTypes = vm.installationTypes.filter((element) => {
                return element.contractType === event.contractType
              })
              let installation = document.getElementById('insediamento')
              installation.innerHTML = ''
              installation.disabled = false
              for (let i = 0; i < filterdTypes.length; i++) {
                installation.options[i] = new Option(
                  filterdTypes[i].name, 
                  filterdTypes[i].id
                )
              }
              installation.value = ""
              let intervention = document.getElementById('tipologia-di-intervento')
              intervention.value = ""
            },
            values: () => {
              return this.contractTypes
            },
          },
          {
            type: "select",
            disabled: "true",
            label: "Insediamento",
            model: "installationType",
            required: true,
            featured: true,
            validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string,
            styleClasses: 'col-12',
            selectOptions: {
              hideNoneSelectedText: true
            },
            onChanged(event) {
              const filterdTypes = vm.interventionTypes.filter((element) => {
                return element.installationType === event.installationType
              })
              let intervention = document.getElementById('tipologia-di-intervento')
              intervention.innerHTML = ''
              intervention.disabled = false
              for (let i = 0; i < filterdTypes.length; i++) {
                intervention.options[i] = new Option(
                  filterdTypes[i].name, 
                  filterdTypes[i].id
                )
              }
              intervention.value = ""
            },
            values: () => {
              return this.isModifying ? this.installationTypes : []
            },
          },
          {
            type: "select",
            disabled: "true",
            noneSelectedText: "",
            label: "Tipologia di intervento",
            model: "interventionType",
            required: true,
            featured: true,
            validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string,
            styleClasses: 'col-12',
            selectOptions: {
              hideNoneSelectedText: true
            },
            values: () => {
              return this.isModifying ? this.interventionTypes : []
            },
          },
          {
            type: "select",
            label: "Referente di progetto",
            model: "contactPerson",
            required: true,
            featured: true,
            validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string,
            styleClasses: 'col-12',
            selectOptions: {
              hideNoneSelectedText: true
            },
            hint: '<div id="new-contact-creation-project"><i class="mdi mdi-account-multiple-plus"></i> <span>Crea nuovo referente</span></div>',
            values: () => {
              return this.contactPersons
            },
          },
          {
            type: "textArea",
            label: "Descrizione",
            model: "description",
            featured: true,
            maxlength: 512,
            validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string,
            styleClasses: 'col-12'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },

  components: {
    FormWizard,
    TabContent,
    'vue-form-generator-component': VueFormGenerator.component,
    VueGoogleAutocomplete
  },

  computed: {
    isModifying() {
       return (this.$router.currentRoute.name == 'builderHome') ? false : true
    },
  },

  methods: {
    ...contractTypesMethods,
    ...installationTypesMethods,
    ...interventionTypesMethods,
    ...contactsMethods,
    ...projectsMethods,
    ...projectManagementMethods,

    onComplete: function (json) {
      if (this.isModifying) {
        this.updateProject({
          projectId: this.currentProject().id,
          name: this.model.projectName,
          description: this.model.description,
          address: this.model.address.partialStreet,
          streetNumber: this.model.address.streetNumber,
          city: this.model.address.city,
          province: this.model.address.province,
          country: this.model.address.country,
          zipCode: this.model.address.CAP,
          contactPerson: this.model.contactPerson,
          contractType: this.model.contractType,
          installationType: this.model.installationType,
          interventionType: this.model.interventionType
        }).then(() => location.reload())
      } else {
        this.addProject(json)
        .then(response => {
          if (response) {
            this.$router.push({
                  name: 'BOMUpload',
                  params: { projectId: response.data.data.createProject.project.id }
              })
          }
        })
      }
    },
    validateFirstTab: function () {
      if (!this.model.projectName) {
        return alert('Il nome del progetto è obbligatorio')
      }
      return this.$refs.firstTabForm.validate();
    },
    validateSecondTab: function () {
      return this.$refs.secondTabForm.validate();
    },

    newContactPersonCreation() {
      this.$emit('new-contact-person-creation')
    },
    
    getAddressData: function (addressData, placeResultData) {
      this.address = addressData;
      this.model.address.country = addressData.country;
      this.model.address.city = addressData.locality;
      if (placeResultData.address_components[4].short_name == 'IT') {
        this.model.address.province = placeResultData.address_components[2].short_name
      } else if (placeResultData.address_components[4].short_name.length > 2) {
        this.model.address.province = placeResultData.address_components[3].short_name
      } else {
        this.model.address.province = placeResultData.address_components[4].short_name
      }
      this.model.address.partialStreet = addressData.route;
      this.model.address.streetNumber = addressData.street_number;
      this.model.address.CAP = addressData.postal_code;
      this.model.address.state = addressData.administrative_area_level_1;
    },

    getContacts() {
      fetchContacts()
      .then(response => {
        this.contactPersons = response.map(contact => {
          return { id: contact.node.id, name: contact.node.name }
        })
        this.model.contactPerson = this.contactPersons.slice(-2).pop().id
        if (this.isModifying) {
          this.model.contactPerson = this.currentProject().contactPerson.id
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.error('Riga 417 ProjectWizard.vue', err))
    }
  },

  mounted() {

    if (this.isModifying) {
      this.model.projectName = this.currentProject().name
      this.model.address.partialStreet = this.currentProject().address.address
      this.model.address.streetNumber = this.currentProject().address.streetNumber
      this.model.address.city = this.currentProject().address.city
      this.model.address.province = this.currentProject().address.province
      this.model.address.country = this.currentProject().address.country
      this.model.address.CAP = this.currentProject().address.zipCode      
      this.model.description = this.currentProject().description
    }

    var newContact = document.querySelector("#new-contact-creation-project")
    newContact.onclick = () => {
      this.newContactPersonCreation()
    };

    // CONTRACT TYPES
    this.fetchContractTypes()
      .then(response => {
        if (response) {
          let processedContractTypes = []
          this.contractTypes = this.allContractTypes()
      
          this.contractTypes.forEach(contractType => {
            let contractTypeObj = { id: contractType.node.id, name: contractType.node.name }
            processedContractTypes.push(contractTypeObj)
          })

          this.contractTypes = processedContractTypes

          if (this.isModifying){
            this.model.contractType = this.currentProject().contractType.id
          }

        } else {
          alert('Not working fetchContractTypes')
        }
      })

    // INSTALLATION TYPES
    this.fetchInstallationTypes()
      .then(response => {
        if (response) {
          let processedInstallationTypes = []
          this.installationTypes = this.allInstallationTypes()

          this.installationTypes.forEach(installationType => {
            let installationTypeObj = { 
              id: installationType.node.id, 
              name: installationType.node.name,
              contractType: installationType.node.contractType.id
            }
            processedInstallationTypes.push(installationTypeObj)
          })

          this.installationTypes = processedInstallationTypes

          if (this.isModifying){
            this.model.installationType = this.currentProject().installationType.id
          }

        } else {
          alert('Not working fetchInstallationTypes')
        }
      })

    // INTERVENTION TYPES
    this.fetchInterventionTypes()
      .then(response => {
        if (response) {
          let processedInterventionTypes = []
          this.interventionTypes = this.allInterventionTypes()

          this.interventionTypes.forEach(interventionType => {
            let interventionTypeObj = {
              id: interventionType.node.id,
              name: interventionType.node.name,
              installationType: interventionType.node.installationType.id,
            }
            processedInterventionTypes.push(interventionTypeObj)
          })

          this.interventionTypes = processedInterventionTypes

          if (this.isModifying){
            this.model.interventionType = this.currentProject().interventionType.id
          }

        } else {
          alert('Not working fetchInterventionTypes')
        }
      })

    // CONTACT PERSONS
    this.getContacts()
  },
}
</script>
```

- this is my jest configuration file:

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  roots: ["<rootDir>/src/", "<rootDir>/src/specs/"],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'json', 'vue'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    "~(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1"
  },
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2|svg)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
    "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest"
  },
  snapshotSerializers: [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue"
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!vue-google-autocomplete)',
    '<rootDir>/(?!)'
  ]
}
```

- and finally this is the code in the spec file:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vue from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import Component from '@/src/components/builder/ProjectWizard'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

describe('ProjectWizard', () => {
  it('should render a card for each project received from its parent', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Component)
    console.log(wrapper)
  })
})
```

I dont't understand why Jest isn't able to find those functions since the module's location is right.

Comment: Maybe provide the code of `ProjectWizard.vue`?

Comment: importing or requiring from `node_modules` with a relative path is non-standard and redundant, and **may** be messing with webpack and causing problems. I'd try `import VueGoogleAutocomplete from 'vue-google-autocomplete'` instead.